# systemd-timesyncd not starting with /var set as a rw ubifs volume

Tags: debian, systemd, systemd-resolved

I am running debian with systemd version 241.  I have a nand flash ubifs partition for my rootfs that I have split into two volumes (/dev/ubi0_1 for rootfs and /dev/ubi0_2 for var):

```
ubi0:rootfs on / type ubifs (ro,relatime,assert=read-only,ubi=0,vol=1)
/dev/ubi0_2 on /var type ubifs (rw,relatime,assert=read-only,ubi=0,vol=2)
```

systemd-timesyncd gives me the following error on boot:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details.
```

journalctl gives the following:

```
Mar 13 22:46:45 nelson systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
Mar 13 22:46:45 nelson systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Read-only file system
Mar 13 22:46:45 nelson systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

If I switch the rootfs to rw then the error goes away.

Here is the output of ls -l /var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-timesync systemd-timesync 0 Mar 13 21:09 /var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock
```

I also see a similar issue with systemd-resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my build (Debian Buster) that /tmp was not being set as a tmpfs automatically.  So I turned on the tmp mount in systemd as follows:

```
cp /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system/
systemctl enable tmp.mount
```

Both journalctl and resolved require write access to /tmp